# An error has occurred. See error log for more details. java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, hibernate

when I want to create file `hibernate.hbm.xml`, eclipse load error message like:

> "An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException "

Why?

One more thing about error system when I run main file I also get error :

```
"log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
 log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
 log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;
 at TestPerson.main(TestPerson.java:29)"
```

Comment: Where is your code, and where is the error occurring?

Comment: problem I guess is with the Hibernate version you are using .Please run a mvn dependency:tree to check for the dependencies.

Comment: Post your code. Without  it's  all guesses.

Comment: >Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: Person

Comment: Maybe you should not mix different errors. In the question it is `NoSuchMethodError ... at TestPerson.main(TestPerson.java:29)`. In your stacktrace it is `MappingException ... at SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1031)`. But your initial question was about `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

`Unknown entity: Person`, add the hibernate mapping entry in hibernate configuration file.

Example:

```
<mapping resource="com.Person.hbm.xml"/>
```